# VS2017 Blank Sign In Screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, msdn

I have a unique issue with my installation of Visual Studio 2017 where the sign in dialog is blank, and no matter how long I wait it never seems to allow me to log in.

I have tried changing the default browser to Chrome, Edge and IE just in case it was using that under the hood for rendering this page. Prior to that I had an issue with the Virtual Machine running the IDE which required me to re-register *.VBS associations to complete the install, that has been resolved and the install has passed.

I am now just left with the sign in issue as shown below:

[image]

Has anyone had this before / know of a work around here? I have been looking around on Google for similar issues but to no avail.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I just encountered this issue myself on Visual Studio 2017 (30-day evaluation expired too so Eduardo Zavala's suggestion isn't possible).  The cause is that I have Internet Explorer 11 installed and set to be extremely restrictive security wise.  For example, it will not follow a redirect if a webpage tells it to.  It also has JavaScript disabled.  Apparently, Visual Studio uses Internet Explorer 11 (or at least "Internet Options" rules) for this login page instead of the default browser (e.g. Microsoft Edge) and its settings.

1. Start Internet Explorer 11.
2. Click on the gear icon in the upper right corner.
3. Click "Internet Options."
4. Click on the "Security" tab.
5. Click "Default level" button.
6. Click "Apply."
7. Click "OK."

Run Visual Studio 2017 again and sign in.

Set Internet Explorer 11 settings back to how you prefer them.

All should be well in both programs now (VS17 authorized and IE11 restrictive).

Comment: This indeed helped.

Answer (score 10):

I think I found something...

If you go to Help tab and click on Send Feedback >> Report a Problem, a Developer Community forum page will pop-up.

In this page, you will see a sign-in link very much like the one in Visual Studio.

That particular link works, so if you log in to it, then exit the Developer Community Forum, you will have successfully logged into Visual Studio.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this works, thank you.  Just a tip: Make sure and look behind the VS 2017 Community window; the Developer Community forum page is hidden behind, and is not immediately visible.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to work around it by doing the following:
At the account login screen select "Account Options"
Under Environment > Accounts on the Sign-In Options section, change the "Add and Reauthenticate accounts using:" pull down menu to "System Web Browser"
[Options dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1mWX.png)
This will open the dialog box IE or whatever default web browser you use and should allow you to login.

Comment: This is the method I used. Several of the answers here are all similar because the root cause is that the login is 1) via a web browser (so all the normal "I can't get to that site" stuff applies) and 2) is an embedded/old browser (so using an external browser works). I think this is the simplest way to go about it for VS2019 community edition. Cheers!

Comment: This is the way to go if you have policy restrictions in place for IE. In my case, it was impossible to add Trusted Sites within IE.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issues. The problem was with Internet Explorer. My computer has Internet Explorer 8.
Please follow the steps below to fix the issue.

1. Install Internet Explorer 11 - you can download it from the Microsoft [site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/Internet-Explorer-11-for-Windows-7-details.aspx).
2. Restart the computer
3. Relaunch Visual Studio
4. Now sign in.
5. No blank screen will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with VS2019, this ended up being blocked by a web filter and could see logincdn.msauth.net being blocked while signing into VS2019.

I would suggest adding an exception for *.msauth.net to allow the sign-in page to load.

This doesn't appear in the list from Microsoft firewall and proxy URLs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-and-use-visual-studio-behind-a-firewall-or-proxy-server?view=vs-2019

Comment: I also had to add *.msftauth.net

Answer (score 1):

On the signin screen click `Account Options`
[image]

Then change `Embedded web browser` to `System web browser`

[image: browser type]

The login screen now opened up a full browser instead of the blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your default Internet browser to Internet Explorer.

Comment: I wouldn't say this was a browser issue, my default browser was already IE and didn't change how VS2019 sign-in was loading.

Comment: Maybe version of IE is important here. I had same issue and for me change to IE worked.