# Change Visual Studio 2019's Default Sign-In Browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to [sign in to activate Visual Studio 2019 Community](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/signing-in-to-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) but clicking the "sign in" dialog box launches Internet Explorer, which is blocked by my organization's security settings. How can the internal browser that Visual Studio launches be changed to Chrome or another browser?

I have attempted to follow suggestion for changing Visual Studios default browser for debugging but it does not change the internal browser Visual Studio uses. Is the only workaround to have the system administrator [add Team Services  as trusted site (eg https://*.visualstudio.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/browsers/cannot-sign-in-to-vsts) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172794/vs2017-blank-sign-in-screen) or is there a way to use an alternate browser such as Chrome?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: I am using 2022 and have replaced my system web browser with edge, which does not seem to have the same issue. IE has been deprecated.

Comment: OMG it's 2023 this problem has been around for years.  IE is long dead.  So frustrating that MS does not even acknowledge the issue

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, and found [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improving-the-authentication-experience-for-enterprises-leveraging-conditional-access-policies/#system-web-browser-authentication-flow) from 2020 describing how to update this setting.  In short, you can find it in the options (under Tools menu), on the Environment/Accounts section:

[image: Options screenshot]